# Html Big Arrow Size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to draw big arrow but I couldn't make it more bigger. Can you help me please?I tried font-size, width attributes but it does not work.

```
 <html>
 <td>&#8679;</td> 
 </html>
```

Comment: How you try with font-size that don't work ? https://jsfiddle.net/qfundgsq/

Comment: This question has been edited by OP and is now a completely different question...

Comment: Rollback to version 1, the sense of the question has been changed in version 2. Next time, ask **another question**.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell the html that you want the arrow to be *big*.  The more bigger you want it, the more bigger you should tell it to be.

```html
<big>&#8679;</big>


<big><big><big><big>&#8679;</big></big></big></big>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using something like [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).

then you can do something like:

```css
div {
  font-size:50px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't change a question after it has been answered. Instead ask a new question.

However, in answer to your new question. You can do this (using jQuery):

```js
$(".number").change(function(){
 var num1 = $("#number1").val();
  var num2 = $("#number2").val();
  var arrow = "";
  if(num1 > num2 ) {arrow =  "&#8679;";}
  if(num1 < num2 ) {arrow =  "&#8681;";}
  if(num1 == num2 ) {arrow =  "&#8680;";}
  $("#arrow").html(arrow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="number" id="number1" type="number">
<input class="number" id="number2" type="number">
<big id="arrow"></big>
```

Comment: I rollbacked the question to version 1.